# How to have multiple queries in one request while keeping order?

Tags: sqlite

I have these three queries:

```
SELECT name, desc, data 
FROM   verbs 
WHERE  name LIKE 'query' ESCAPE '\'



SELECT name, desc, data
FROM   verbs
WHERE  name LIKE '%query%' ESCAPE '\'
LIMIT  5



SELECT name, desc, data
FROM   verbs
WHERE  data LIKE '%\"query\"]%' ESCAPE '\'
LIMIT  5
```

Is it possible to have all of this in one query but also make sure that the items from the first query stay on top, followed by those that accept query 2 and then followed by the third one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for example with this trick

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT col1, col2, '1' as ord ...
  UNION 
  SELECT col1, col2, '2' as ord ...
  UNION
  SELECT col1, col2, '3' as ord ... 
) AS tmp
ORDER BY ord ASC
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` would be more efficient.

Comment: You are right @CL. if either the 3 queries return different results or the OP don't mind about the duplicates. Thanks.